# powershell Get-NetAdapter command not recognized

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I am running Windows 7 Home Premium.
I installed .Net4.5.1 and Powershell 4.0
It installed successfully. I can verify that because this command returns:

```
PS C:\Users\Aubrey\Documents> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
4      0      -1     -1
```

However I cant run commands or scripts:

```
PS C:\Users\Aubrey\Documents> Get-NetAdapter
Get-NetAdapter : The term 'Get-NetAdapter' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if 
a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-NetAdapter
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-NetAdapter:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/01/15/using-powershell-to-find-connected-network-adapters.aspx, the NetAdapter module (and therefore the Get-NetAdapter command) needs Windows 8 or better.

Answer (score 1):

Network Setup Service must be running for "Get-NetAdapter" command to return anything in (Windows 10) PowerShell